# How to change last parameter in file by first

Tags: python, list, file

This program must change the last parameter on a line based on the starting code.

*File now:*

```
312|fotelja snesko|bela|15|2900|fotelja|False
621|digimon tabure|crna|25|850|tabure|False
```

Code is:>> 312

*File after:*

```
312|fotelja snesko|bela|15|2900|fotelja|True
621|digimon tabure|crna|25|850|tabure|False
```

My work right now.

```
parameter = input("\nCode is >> ")

with open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r") as fileNAME:
    allDATA = fileNAME.readlines()
    for linija in allDATA:
        linija = linija.split("|")

        if parameter == linija[0]:
            linija[6] = "True"
```

With this I read every line in the file and found the line that I need. I just need to change `False` to `True` in that line. How can I change it?

Comment: as it looks like you successfully set the new value, just use join('|') to build the new string and write it back to a file.

Comment: Yes i can do it, but how i can delete old with False on end ?

Comment: I see, you have accepted an answer. If you have to perform such tasks often, looking into the tools 'sed' (streaming editor) and 'awk' could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, your file is not too large(let's say 1 GB), no need of a temporary file. Below solution can help you. The idea is to:

1. Convert the file contents to a list
2. Split the innerLists
3. modify the list based on your condition
4. form the innerLists
5. finally writing it back to the same file.
6. open mode should be `r+`, so that it can both read and write to the file.

Let's see the code below:

```
with open('komad_namestaja.txt','r+') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    output_data=[]
    for i in data:
        lst=i.split("|")
        if(lst[0]=='312'):
            lst[-1]='True\n'
        output_data.append("|".join(lst))
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(output_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is open a temporary file, write your result to that file and then replace the old file with your new file:

```
fh, abs_path = mkstemp()  # Create a temporary file
with open(abs_path,'w') as new_file:
    with open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r") as old_file:
        for line in old_file:
            linija = linija.split("|")
                if parameter == linija[0]:
                    linija[6] = "True"
            new_file.write(linija)
close(fh)
remove("komad_namestaja.txt")  # Remove original file
move(abs_path, "komad_namestaja.txt")  # Move new file to old file location
```